# Array dimensions must match for binary array op in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, pixel, addition, dimensions

Array dimensions must match for binary array op in Matlab. How to solve this problem?

```
clc;
clear;
Image1 = imread('rowoon2.jpg'); %500x738 pixels
Image2 = imread('rowoon7.jpg'); %780x1169 pixels

ImageAdd = Image1+Image2;
subplot (2,2,1)
imshow (Image1);
title ('Image 1');
subplot (2,2,2)
imshow (Image2);
title ('Image 2');
subplot (2,2,3)
imshow (ImageAdd);
title ('Addition Result');
```

This error also occurs in subtraction, multiplication, and division operations, pls help

Comment: What does a sum of a 500x738 pixels image with a 780x1169 pixels one look like in your head? Because in mine it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The summation of two images with different dimensions does not conceptually work. You'll have to resize one to match the dimensions of the other in order to perform such a summation.
However, you'll also have to think about whether downsampling or upsampling better fits your needs.

Matlab provides the function [imresize](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) as part of the *Image Processing Toolbox*.

For example, using two test images from matlab:

```
clc;
clear;

Image1 = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png')); % 650x600 pixels
Image2 = rgb2gray(imread('ngc6543a.jpg')); % 384x512pixels

ImageAdd = Image1+imresize(Image2, size(Image1));
subplot (2,2,1)
imshow (Image1);
title ('Image 1');
subplot (2,2,2)
imshow (Image2);
title ('Image 2');
subplot (2,2,3)
imshow (ImageAdd);
title ('Addition Result');
```

Resulting in:

[image: Output]